# How to hide label of data points in line chart

Tags: c#, mschart, linechart

Please refer to the picture below.

Basically I have a C# chart control with some series on it, I have one series with label (the red line in the picture) but I want to be able to toggle the label on/off. Is that possible? I can't find any properties that can do so.

Thanks a lot.

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of clearing the text of the `labels` one simple method is to make the color transparent.

You can do it for the whole `Series s1`:

```
s1.LabelForeColor = checkBox_test.Checked ? Color.Black: Color.Transparent;
```

..or for individual `DataPoints dp`:

```
dp.LabelForeColor = checkBox_test.Checked ? Color.Blue : Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: Just what I want! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: This will leave the label arrows visible.

Comment: What arrows? Do you see any in the image above?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution is to store the labels to the custom properties of the points and assign the values to [DataPoint.Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.label?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-windows-forms-datavisualization-charting-datapointcustomproperties-label) when the labels are toggled on.

```
/* Store the labels to the custom properties on initialization. */
series.Points[index].SetCustomProperty("Label", "My label");

/* .... */
if (checkboxLabels.Checked) 
{
    /* If the labels are toggled on, initialize the Label property. */
    var label = series.Points[index].GetCustomProperty("Label");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label))
    {
        series.Points[index].Label = label;
    }
}
else 
{
    /* Otherwise, erase it. */
    series.Points[index].Label = "";
}
```